# Are there constants for infinity?

Tags: rascal

I notice that Rascal supports big integers.  But I cannot find constants for infinity.  Do they exist?  If not, I would suggest add them since the sometimes they are quite useful.  Currently, my workaround is to define something like `int pInf = 1024`, but it may fail for extreme cases.

Comment: What is the use for infinity constants?

Comment: I am not sure in general.  But in my Lisp implementation, I want to specify the arity of the Lisp function `list` which accepts an arbitrary number of arguments.  In an arity check, it should be greater than any number of arguments passed to this function, however large.

Comment: The "Rascal" way of dealing with such variability is to introduce an algebraic data-type, as in:
`data Arity = inf() | fixed(int size)`, then you can use pattern matching or `is` or whatever to deal with the differences. `if (arity is inf) {...}` or `int foo(fixed(int size)) = ...; int foo(inf()) = ...;`

Comment: Ah, good idea.  Did not think of that.  This is indeed a better solution so as to avoid relying on the implementation.  If you put it into an answer, I can choose to accept it.

Comment: ok cool. I just edited my previous answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No support for infinity in Rascal.

The "Rascal" way of dealing with such variability is to introduce an algebraic data-type, as in:

```
data Arity = inf() | fixed(int size)
```

Then you can use pattern matching or is or whatever to deal with the differences.

```
if (arity is inf) {...}
int foo(fixed(int size)) = ...; 
int foo(inf()) = ...;
```

Answer (score 2):

Rational numbers in Rascal actually support infinity (in the form of a zero denominator), but that's more a side effect of the implementation than a real design choice, so you may not want to count on it. I also can't guarantee that all corner cases are handled correctly.

For example,

```
rascal>1r0
rat: 1r0

rascal>1r0*2
rat: 1r0

rascal>-1r0
rat: -1r0

rascal>-1r0*(-2)
rat: 1r0

rascal>1 / 1r0
rat: 0r

rascal>12345678901234567890 > 1r0
bool: false

rascal>25r0
rat: 1r0

rascal>25 / 0
|stdin:///|(5,1,<1,5>,<1,6>): ArithmeticException("/ by zero")


rascal>25 / 0r
rat: 1r0
```

Comment: Ha, interesting.  But it seems I could not find documentation about rational numbers in help.

Comment: Some experimentation told me that Rascal does not do automatic up-casting from integers to rationals.  Does any library function do this?

Comment: Ah,I see. Yes, it does seem to be undocumented in the tutor. Basically, the idea is that literal rationals are written ArB, where A is the numerator and B is the denominator. You can also write Ar for whole-integer rationals (e.g., 1r). The type name is 'rat'. All normal numerical operators are available, and ints will be promoted to rats as necessary (rats are also promoted to reals when needed). Basic arithmetic should be well-tested and safe.

Comment: It does upcasting for me: 1 + 0r => 1r; also 1 > 0r works. Even 1 == 1r (you have no idea how long we fought with that one). But, [1] != [1r].

Comment: Really?  I defined an `id` function on rational, when applying it to an integer, I got a type mismatch error.

Comment: Ah, maybe it only does it for built-in operators. Same thing happens for reals, it seems. There's a toRat() function in `util::Math`: `toRat(x, 1)` will convert an int. `toInt` will convert back to int (rounding down).

Comment: Thanks.  Someone should update the documentation, :)

Comment: Having 1r0 was a sub-conscious design choice ;-) we are algebraists.

Comment: @jurgenv: actually, I consciously snuck it in, hoping you wouldn't notice. ;)

Comment: @anya of course I would notice, but I wouldn't mind. it makes total sense to me. just that I would not advise to depend on it :-)

Comment: So, for convenience operators are overloaded on combinations of different types. Such as == is overloaded for int == rat and rat == int, doing the expected conversions (towards more precision), but for other values list[rat] == list[int] it calls normal equality where you can assume that 1r1 != 1 (since we use value/structural equality everywhere.